# Return button in flask

Tags: python, flask, button

I'm learning to use Flask but I did not found a "easy solution" (by "easy solution" I mean easy for my noob level, few codes line) for this so I'm asking here for help.

How I can create a "back" button on the new generated page in flask?

This is my code:

calculator.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def my_form():
    return render_template("calc.html")

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    num_1 = request.form['Number 1']
    num_2 = request.form['Number 2']
    result = int(num_1) + int(num_2)
    render = render_template("calc_result.html")
    #return render_template("calc_result.html")
    return "The result from " + str(num_1) + " plus " + str(num_2) + " is: " + str(result) + "."


app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

calc.html

```
<html>
    <body>

    <form method = "POST">
    <input name = "Number 1">
    <input name = "Number 2">
    <input type = "submit">
    
    </body>
</form>
```

The code is working, is receiving the numbers and doing the math but the problem is, I'm not able to generate a "back" button in the new generated page with the result.

If I put for example 10 + 10 in the calc.html, I will receive:

> The result from 10 plus 10 is: 20.

I would like to put a "back" button on this page or learn how to generate a new button in the new gelerated page, so I would receive something like:

> The result from 10 plus 10 is: 20.

> Back

Sorry the english.

---

Edit:

This is what user see on the first page:

[What user see in first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkt0F.png)

After put the two numbers to sum, they see:

[Result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBVWt.png)

I want allow user to come back to first page and be able to do another sum.

In both pages the link are the same: http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Comment: What do you want the "back" button to do? Do you want it to erase the text in your calculator?

Comment: Sorry, didn't made this point clear. I want to return to the first page where users can see the the blank fields and do the math again. LIke a calculator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
  window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

Please refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp).

Answer (score 0):

in your 'calc_result.html' file, make a link or button and use the 'url_for' command to bring you back to your 'calc.html' page. Flask allows you to insert Python code into your HTML via jinja templates. Check out the quickstart guide [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/). So:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('my_form') }}">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/">
    <form action="/">
         <input class="btn" type="button" value="HOME" />
    </form>
</a>
```